# how can I get Viking, on Ubuntu 16.04, to recognize my gps unit, a Garmin eTrex 20x?

Tags: usb, gps

How can I get Viking, or any other interface program, while using Ubuntu 16.04, to recognize my gps unit, a Garmin eTrex 20x?

My gps device is recognized to some extent by my computer.

The output of `lsusb` shows it can see it.

```
Bus 007 Device 008: ID 091e:28ca Garmin International
```

I have followed through several on-line tutorials and advice. As such I have changed the udev rules with:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-garmin.rules
```

adding the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="091e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="28ca" MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

This gave me read-write permission:

```
$ ls -al /dev/bus/usb/007/008
crw-rw-rw- 1 root plugdev 189, 775 Jul 19 17:52 /dev/bus/usb/007/008
```

I also blacklisted my device in power settings with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

and changed it to

```
USB_BLACKLIST="091e:28ca"
```

I've downloaded Viking, gpsd, gpsBabel, gpsMan, others...

Yet nothing seems to see it or be able to communicate with it. Ultimately, I really just want to be able to upload a decent map to my GPS unit, but nothing seems to be able to interact with it.

Any ideas??

Comment: The steps [mentioned here](http://hselab.org/garmin-gps-ubuntu.html) didn't work for you ?

Comment: Hi Sirajus, everything went fine until I got to $ gpsbabel -i garmin -f usb:1 which produced no result and timed out with the message "Could not start session in a reasonable number of tries." Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: I tried running the gpsbabel command with sudo - same result

Comment: usb:1 is from the tutorial, try your usb number, 7 or 8 or something that gpsbable hopefully documents.I thought most gps programs like viking these days just run off the gpsd, and let it handle the gps device directly.

Comment: My error. I should have pointed out I moved to a different machine and usb:1 is the correct bus on that machine.